# Changing EditText input to a string when a certain key is pressed android

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard-events

I have a `EditText` in my app. I want to override the `@` key functionality such that as soon as the user hits the `@` key while giving input in the `EditText`, the @ should be replaced by some string like "Hello world".

I have created something like below which shows a toast message when I hit the @ key. But I dont know how to implement it while working with a EditText.

Here is my code:-

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(editText1.isFocused() && event.isShiftPressed() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 )
        {
            //txtSample.setText("Hello");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InputFilter is the Proper way to do this kind of stuffs.

Proper Working Demo

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source != null && ("" + source).equals("@")) {
                return "Hello World";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });

    }

}
```

Comment: works great! thanks. BTW any idea if this can we achieved for EditText Fields inside a WebView?

Answer (score 0):

```
mMyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
    {
        /*This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by new text with length after. It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.*/ 
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
    }
);
```

in this code if on onTextChanged s==@ then replace it with Hello World

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is if I enter `abc@` in the `EditText`, as soon as I hit the @ key the text should get added after my input like `abc@xyz.com`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
String replacedText = txtSample.getText().replace("@","Hello World");
txtSample.setText(replacedText);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But I guess you misunderstood the question. I want to change the text in the EditText to something else as soon as the user presses a certain key

Comment: I just write the code to replace with your toast statement.